# Removing negative duplicates of values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array:

```
var arr = [-1, -5, 4, 5, 3];
```

How would I remove any negative versions of a number in the array? So the output would be:

```
[-1, 4, 5, 3]
```

Comment: [Remove duplicates from javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @ASDFGerte no, because these aren't duplicates. They are duplicates in the absolute value.

Comment: I've looked at the removing duplicates question, and tried those methods, but they're for removing duplicates and not negative duplicates.

Comment: @ItamarG3 in all solutions posted there, mapping negative to positive is not too hard - replacing the search in the related code to associate negative with positive. I also did not say duplicate per-se, i just linked to the base topic.

Comment: what should `[-5,-5,1,2,3]` be?

Comment: @Psidom o.o hit blunt.

Comment: @Psidom [-5, 1, 2, 3]. So removing all duplicates and negative duplicates

Comment: this was an important case, handled it, best add it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would filter out all variables which are negative and have a positive part in the array

```js
var arr = [-1, -5, 4, 5, 3, -5];

arr = arr.filter(function(a, b){
  if(a < 0 && arr.indexOf(-1*a) > -1){
    return 0;
  }
  if(a < 0 && arr.indexOf(a) != b){
   return 0;
  }
  return 1;
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` with `Math.abs()`

```js
var arr1 = [-1, -5, 5, 4, 3];
var arr2 = [-1, -5, -5, 4, 3];


function customFilter(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(e) {
    if (e > 0) return true;
    else {
      var abs = Math.abs(e)
      if (arr.indexOf(abs) != -1) return false;
      else return !this[e] ? this[e] = 1 : false;
    }
  }, {})
}

console.log(customFilter(arr1))
console.log(customFilter(arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array, and add all those that don't have their absolue value already in the second array:

```
var noDups = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, v){
    if($.inArray(abs(v), noDups) === -1 || $.inArray(v,noDups)===-1){
        noDups.push(v);
    }
});
```

This was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array), which is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the sign or if the absolute value is not included.

```js
var array = [-1, -5, 4, 5, 3],
    result = array.filter((a, _, aa) => a >= 0 || !aa.includes(Math.abs(a)));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Filter

```js
var arr = [-1, -5, 4, 5, 3, 4, -6, 4, 6];

console.log(removeNegativesCommon(arr));

function removeNegativesCommon(arr){
  return arr.filter((el) => {
    if( el < 0 && arr.indexOf(Math.abs(el)) != -1){
      return false;
    } else {
      return el;
    }
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that does not use repeated `indexOf`. It uses a solution from [my previously linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array) (uniq function) along with a prior removal of negatives that already are included as positives.

```js
var arr = [-1, -5, 4, 5, 3];

function uniq(a) {
    var seen = {};
    return a.filter(function(item) {
        return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
    });
}

function preRemoveNegatives(a) {
  let table = {};
  a.filter(e => e >= 0).forEach(e => table[e] = true);
  return a.filter(e => e >= 0 || !table[-e]);
}

console.log(uniq(preRemoveNegatives(arr)));
```